# DynamoDB - Enhanced API: How to query using LSI

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index, dynamodb-enhanced-client

I am new to DynamoDB. I am using DynamoDB Enhanced Client API to query items using LSI, but I am not getting the item I expected.

Test Scenario

> I have 2 items in the table with same primary key (PK) and seatId (lsi sort key) is different for both these records. When I query item for specific PK and seatId I am getting both items

Can someone please tell what is wrong with the code.

I have created LSI with seatId as sortkey and PK is the partition key.
LSI index name is seatId-index.

```
@DynamoDbBean
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
public class PassengerEntity {

    private String pk;
    private String sk;
    private String seatId;

    @DynamoDbPartitionKey
    @DynamoDbAttribute(value = "PK")
    public String getPk() {
        return pk;
    }
    public void setPk(String pk) {
        this.pk = pk;
    }

    @DynamoDbSortKey
    @DynamoDbAttribute(value = "SK")
    public String getSk() {
        return sk;
    }
    public void setSk(String sk) {
        this.sk = sk;
    }

    @DynamoDbSecondarySortKey(indexNames = "seatId-index")
    public String getSeatId() {
        return seatId;
    }
    public void setSeatId(String seatId) {
        this.seatId = seatId;
    }
}

public Optional<PassengerEntity> getPassengerDetailsByBookingFlightlegAndSeatId(String pk, String seatId) {
        Optional<PassengerEntity> passengerDetail = Optional.empty();
        DynamoIndex lsiIndex1 = dynamoTableConfig.getDepartureData().getLsiIndex1();

        DynamoDbIndex<PassengerEntity> seatIndex = passengerDetailTable.index(lsiIndex1.getIndexName());

        QueryConditional seatIndexQuery = QueryConditional.keyEqualTo(Key.builder()
                .partitionValue(pk)
                .sortValue(seatId)
                .build());

      SdkIterable<Page<PassengerEntity>> results = seatIndex.query(QueryEnhancedRequest.builder()
          .queryConditional(seatIndexQuery)
          .build());

      for (Page<PassengerEntity> page:results) {
          if (!page.items().isEmpty()) {
              passengerDetail = Optional.of(page.items().get(0));
          }
      }

      return passengerDetail;
    }
```

Comment: yes, PK is same

Table
-----
Partition key: PK (String) |
Sort key: SK (String) ||

LSI Details
-----------
Name: seatId-index |
Partition key: PK (String) |
Sort key: seatId (String) |
Projected attributes: all

Comment: Can you enable debug logging for the AWS SDK? Try to determine what DynamoDB query is actually being generated, or enable [data plane API activity in CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/logging-using-cloudtrail.html). It sounds like it's simply querying on the PK but not the seatId sort key.

Comment: Hi, the above code is working fine. It was issue with data. Thanks for your help.